# Parse a JSON string in JS from CPP TCP connection

Tags: javascript, c++, json, tcp

I have a JSON string coming from a C++ TCP client. My server is in JS (which I am not as familiar with). I am attempting to parse the incoming JSON for 'error' keyword and if it is found, output the content message. I'm having issues on the receiving side. I cant figure out how to set the data in buffer to a JSON object and then parse for the keyword.

Any help/guidance is appreciated. Thank you!

CPP code that sends message (tcpSock.send sends JSON string):

```
int errorMsg(const std::string& msg, int val) {
    // send TCP message to the server
    // create JSON object
    json j_err;
    j_err["error"] = msg;
    
    // put the JSON object into a string so we can serialize it
    std::string err(j_err.dump());

    // send data
    if ( ( tcpSock.send("oui", reinterpret_cast<uint8_t*>(err.data()), err.size()) ) < 0) {
        return -1;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Visual representation of the JSON error message:
Only one error message gets sent at a time. This shows two sent back to back.

[image]

and JS server side code that should check for 'error' keyword and if found, prompt user.

```
    socket.on('data', function(data) {

        let msg = JSON.stringify(data);
        
        // Catching 'ERROR' keyword from SOS and displaying the error to the user if it exists. 

        // Output error message to console. 
        if (msg.hasOwnProperty('error')) {
            console.log('\n\nERROR: ' + msg.error);
        }
        else{
            console.log(`Inbound Data: ${data.toString()}`);
            socket.write('Data recieved.\r\n');
        }
    });
```

Comment: A string will not have an `error` property.  `data`, is that is an object, might have it.

Comment: You mean JSON.parse, not JSON.stringify.

Comment: replacing JSON.stringify with JSON.parse on server side corrected my issue, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @Anonymous1847 for the input, this corrected the issue; proper code below for anyone that finds this post.

Utilizing JSON.parse instead of JSON.stringify

```
socket.on('data', function(data) {

        let msg = JSON.parse(data);
        
        // Output error message to console. 
        if (msg.hasOwnProperty('error')) {
            console.log('\n\nERROR: ' + msg.error);
        }
        else{
            console.log(`Inbound Data: ${data.toString()}`);
            socket.write('Data recieved.\r\n');
        }
    });
```